# Showing Revmob full screen ad above nextpeer multiplayer screen

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, revmob, nextpeer

I am using [Nextpeer](http://nextpeer.com) to add multiplayer facility in my game. Now i want to show ad when user start the game so I show ad when user press start button. but the problem is the the Revmob full screen goes under that screen. I want to that ad should appear above that Nextpeer screen.
Any guide or help

Comment: This looks like a bug on RevMob SDK, you should contact them.

Comment: Hi Developer, Nextpeer CTO here. Contact our support at support@nextpeer.com if you have any questions for us.

Comment: I had mail support of Nextpeer. Lets see when there response comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allowed to show an ad when user start the game and on Nextpeer screens as long as you don't block Nextpeer ads.

You can read more about our pricing plans for developers in this [link](http://nextpeer.com/pricing)

Comment: Not feeling good to listen this. I think you should allow full screen ads because this will not effect your sdk promotion directly or indirectly.